# Why Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Cloud images don't come with backported kernels?

Tags: kernel, cloud, lts

Why the latest Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS Cloud Images (http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release) does not come with the latest kernel, the linux-generic-lts-raring ?

Any special reason to not ship it to the cloud?

Can I just install the linux-generic-lts-raring into my EC2 and/or OpenStack Instances without any problem?! I see they work but, I would like to know why it is not shipped by default.

Thanks!
Thiago

Answer (score 1):

The [hardware enablement stack's](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) primary task is to provide newer kernels so they work on newer hardware.

Since clouds are virtualized, there's really no reason for us to ship those kernels as cloud users can just stay on the stock 12.04 kernel.

That being said it is nice to enjoy the new kernel features that you get with the backported kernels, so installing `linux-generic-lts-raring` as you guess is totally fine, and still supported.

Ironically, if you're deploying on MAAS or OpenStack we still default to the stock 12.04 kernel, but we're aware of that and have started discussions on how we can make it easier for users to do that.

Comment: Cool! Thanks! I'll try btrfs for my Cassandra commitlog and, Linux 3.8 have a better support for a BetterFS... hehe... Cheers!